# jQuery ui split button glitch

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, visual-glitch, split-button

Using a jQuery UI split button with a drop down menu over an `ui-state-disabled` table row will make some menu options unreachable. Why?

example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zj7Kv/3/)

Trying to select `Partner 2` option is almost impossible.

Tested in Google Chrome Version 33.0.1750.152 and Firefox 28.0

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a z-index related issue; the row has a `ui-state-disabled` and this affects the elements with the same z-index.

I have fixed it by adding an higher z-index to the menu ul-li.

Code:

```
<ul style="z-index:1">
    <li><a href="?op=viewPromotions" idpartner="0">All partners</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="?op=viewPromotions&amp;idPartner=1" idpartner="3">Partner 1</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="?op=viewPromotions&amp;idPartner=2" idpartner="1">Partner 2</a>

    </li>
</ul>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/zEeb2/